# Webscraping table data in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fetch data from the website using web scraping but getting an error in to_html

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


 url= 
'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm'
 html = requests.get(url).content
 df_list = pd.read_html(html)
 df = df_list.to_html(html)
 print (df)
 df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

Error :

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-61d14e08ca97> in <module>()
      5 html = requests.get(url).content
      6 df_list = pd.read_html(html)
----> 7 df = df_list.to_html(html)
      8 print (df)
      9 df.to_csv('my data.csv')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_html'
```

Comment: df is a list of DataFrames, it has no to_html method. Try printing df_list and you will see a list of all the tables you scraped from the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
pip install lxml
pip install html5lib
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

Now you don't need to import requests.

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
table=pd.read_html('https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm')
```

Also if you are planning to scrape stock data from National Stock Exchange, you can use NSEpy which is a simple API to get Stock data of Indian companies.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works but it lists all table values . Could you please help me to get the specific table from the web page?

Comment: try to get the specific table by using an index. 
eg. table[0]

Answer (score 0):

I believe need select first value of list of DataFrames by indexing:

```
df = df_list[0]
print (df)
          0
0  No Data.

df.to_csv('my data.csv', index=False)
```

**Detail**:

```
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
print (df_list)
[          0
0  No Data.]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the AttributeError because pd.read_html() returns a list of dataframes and list does not have an attribute 'to_html'

Coming to the solution,
The page you mentioned is rendered using javascript. **BeautifulSoup** does not have the capacity to scrape data from page rendered by a javascript.

To access Javascript-rendered pages you will need to use a full-fledged rendering engine. You can use **selenium** or **phantomJS** to get javascript data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
# !pip install webdriver-manager
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
DRIVER_PATH = '/path/to/chromedriver'
url= 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm'
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
try:
    driver.get(url)
except:
    pass
src= driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup= bs(src, 'lxml')
table= soup.find_all('table')
table= pd.read_html(str(table[1]),header=0)[0].set_index('Symbol')
table
```